# What is the alternative to rel="first"?

Tags: html

Since HTML 5, the `rel=""` attribute (for "Link types") no-longer accepts "first" and "last" as valid values. These keywords are meant to represent the first and last pages in a page sequence, however only "prev" and "next" are supported:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

> - `first` - Indicates that the hyperlink leads to the first resource of the sequence the current page is in. **This is an obsolete API and is no longer guaranteed to work.**
> - `last` - Indicates that the hyperlink leads to the last resource of the sequence the current page is in. **This is an obsolete API and is no longer guaranteed to work.**
> - `next` - Indicates that the hyperlink leads to the next resource of the sequence the current page is in.
> - `prev` - Indicates that the hyperlink leads to the preceding resource of the sequence the current page is in.

Curiously, the HTML 4.01 specification (December 1999) does list "Start" as a valid value - this value does not appear in the HTML5 specification nor Mozilla's MDN page: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links

> `Start` - Refers to the first document in a collection of documents. This link type tells search engines which document is considered by the author to be the starting point of the collection.

Going back further in time, the HTML 3.2 specification (January 1997) does not suggest any "first" or "last" equivalents, only `next` and `previous` ( https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#anchor ).

Does anybody know of a valid alternative for `rel` values `first`/`last`, or should I just carry on using them just in case Google or other search engines still care to understand them?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, the MDN page for the `rel=""` attribute ("Link types") indicates the `first` and `last` values are now deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Comment: @Dai thanks for clarifying that and making the question a whole lot less ambiguous.

Comment: So the question is still unanswered.

Also, does anyone know *why* these values were deprecated? I can see some real value in them, especially with internal anchors, accessibility and so on.

Comment: OK, I dug around and found the relevant working group decision document. It was not all that easy to find, so here is the link

https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Feb/att-0481/issue-118-decision.html

Comment: FWIW, in 2023, `rel="first"` and `rel="last"` are no longer even listed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values were deprecated because they were used rarely and inconsistently. Only a couple of user agents did anything interesting with these values, and many validators did not even check them.

I don't agree with the rationale for deprecating these (because rel may be used for internal anchors too), but I suppose it is a lost cause.

So to answer your question, there is no 'standard' alternative. If you need to add this information to your site, I suggest using a [data- attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead. For example:

```
<link data-rel="first" href="slide01.html />
<link data-rel="last" href="slide999.html />
```

There is a javascript API for accessing these values, and it's valid HTML5. Just don't expect the browser to pay much attention to them.

The whole point of data attributes is to insert whatever data you (as page author/developer) need to associate with a given element. You might ask yourself why you want to add this data, and (more importantly) who/what will consume this data.

Comment: Normally I would shun the rel attribute because my main project at work has a lot of legacy code that misuses rel, so running its output through an HTML validator generates a long list of errors, but I thought I'd implement the rel-ordering on my own website in order to make search engines happy.

Thanks for digging so deep!